# How might being disciplined for participating in a non-violent protest on a public college affect my academic career?

Tags: academic-life, policy, disciplinary-action

I go to a government-owned school that has certain policies regarding a student's speech, namely:

1. That speech shall not be discriminatory/offensive.
2. That on-campus protests take place only at a "Hyde Park" location in the student center.

Suppose I decide to form a protest and violate rule #2, and perhaps unintentionally violate rule #1, incurring a disciplinary action of record. How would my doing so affect my ability to pursue a degree at a different school?

Answer (score 7):

Probably not at all.  Most academic institutions support freedom of speech.  However, this depends on the goal of the protest and the type/location of the hypothetical institution.  For instance, I imagine some religious institutions might not hire someone who had protested for abortion rights.

Answer (score -2):

These policies are at the same time repressive and ridiculous.

First, because the fundamental principle of protesting is causing  inconvenience, annoynance, displeasure - so a designated "speech zone" is the same as "protest where we don't notice you and it doesn't matter".

Second, because any speech that management doesn't like (or that a student group which can put pressure on management to repress speech doesn't like) will be defined to be offensive. It offends them, after all.

Thus the only thing that happened is that you were involved in organizing a protest. If the regime in the state you live in is highly repressive, then maybe that means you'll have trouble getting into another school (although I kind of doubt it); if it isn't, then you won't.

Note that these policies are extremely repressive and are in my opinion contradiction of  fundamental academic principle.